# How to setup my custom domain on gcloud

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I tried using these guides:

> https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart
>
> https://cloud.google.com/dns/migrating

When I ping my domain, I get a response from my compute-engine external IP address, but my WebApp is not loading.

Am I missing something? I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Enterprise Support:

All App Engine services run by default (domain.appspot.com). In order to map your service on your own domain name, please read the following article https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to definitely say what the issue is, but here are some suggestions to troubleshoot.

**Have your registrar's name server records been updated?**

Make sure the following consistently returns Google's name servers for your zone

`$ dig +short NS example.com`

**Have Google's name server propagated the change?**

List your Google name servers -

`$ gcloud dns managed-zones describe examplezonename`

Verify they have propagated -

`$ dig example.com @your_zone_nameserver`

**Are your A and CNAME records set correctly?**

Next you should verify that the DNS reply returns the correct A and CNAME entries.

```
$ dig example.com A
$ dig example.com CNAME
```

**Have you configured your IP and Firewall settings correctly?**

You can follow the troubleshooting guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#communicatewithinternet) or update your question with more details.

It appears that your web server may not be set up correctly and there does not seem to be any process listening on either port 80 or 443.

```
$ nmap queguia.com

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-03 12:16 PDT
Nmap scan report for queguia.com (35.184.29.62)
Host is up (0.15s latency).
rDNS record for 35.184.29.62: 62.29.184.35.bc.googleusercontent.com
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 10.21 seconds
```

**Caveats**

Please also keep in mind that DNS entries are cached and it can take some time for your changes to take effect.

Pings of your external IP are most likely answered by a load balancer and not your instance specifically.

Comment: everything seems to be ok, but still not working :( I'll update the question with more info

Comment: @IgnacioMartínez From what I can tell, this looks like the web server is not properly set up.

`nmap queguia.com

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-03 12:16 PDT
Nmap scan report for queguia.com (35.184.29.62)
Host is up (0.15s latency).
rDNS record for 35.184.29.62: 62.29.184.35.bc.googleusercontent.com
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 10.21 seconds`

Comment: thanks a lot, you help me to understand some concepts and finally I found a solution and it's really simple, take a look